# How to rewrite /?a=a to /a/?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite this URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?a=a
```

To this URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/a/
```

With htaccess?

I tried this rewrite rule but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule /a /?a=a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
RewriteRule ^a/?$ /?a=a [L]
```

This will route `http://mywebsite.com/a/` requests to `http://mywebsite.com/?a=a`

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for an exact match of `?a=a` in the URI you can use this.

```
RewriteRule ^\?a=a$ /a/ [R=301]
```

This assumes you want to rewrite the actual URL in the user's browser and provide a 301 header to let anything crawling the page know about the "proper" URI to use (thus the `[R=301]`).